# Using real football player photo in a trivia quiz game, is it legal?

Tags: legal

I don't know whether this question was already been asked before, but my team is currently developing a trivia quiz game about football (soccer not NFL). And we want to put player's images or club emblems as part of the questions and answers. My question is, is it legal? Or should we just put text without the images? Please your help is much needed. Thank you.

Comment: It's a long read, but it may be worth it: http://www.postmatch.org/251/ronaldo-beckham-aguero-football-image-rights/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lawyer but it is probably not legal -- minimally, the players did not agree to you using their portraits for your own purposes. Then you can assume that the photographer holds the copyright for the photo (or some third party does who acquired the copyright). In addition, there's a good chance that logos, emblems etc. are trademarked so you cannot use those either.